# How to assign return value from json into a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a dropdown list of Tests(Diagnostic) on my view and selecting any Test from that list it should load corresponding Fee into a readonly textbox. 
Here is my View:

```
 <select name="TestId" id="TestId" style="width: 171px;">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                @foreach (var tests in ViewBag.allTests)
                {
                    <option value="@tests.TestId">@tests.TestName</option>
                }
            </select>
 <input type="text" id="TestFee" name="TestFee" readonly="readonly" />

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#TestId").change(function() {
                var testid = $("#TestId").val();

                //$("#fees").empty();

                var json = { testId: testid };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetFeesById", "TestRequest")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#TestFee").val(data.Fee);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

And there is controller:

```
public class TestRequestController : Controller
{
   SaveTestManager manager=new SaveTestManager();
    public ActionResult SaveTestRequest()
    {
        ViewBag.allTests = manager.AllTestViews();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetFeesById(int testId)
    {
        var testlist = manager.AllTestViews().Where(m => testId==m.TestId);
        return Json(testlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
}
```

I used Debugger on my JsonResult, It returns corresponding Data on change of dropdown item. But, my textbox does not get Fee which returned from controller.
Is there any wrong with this code? how could be assign value on textbox?
NB: I never Used Json before, I just trying with the help of some blogs and tutorials. If is there any better way please suggest this as well.
Thanks

Comment: Mention `dataType: "json"` in ajax call

Comment: Not worked #Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 
$("#TestFee").val(data.data[0].Fee);
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.